# Unable to store Web Service response in R

Tags: r, xml, web-services, xml-parsing, rcurl

I have a SOAP request that is getting a correct response in Rstudio as shown in the screenshot below.  The code used to request the response is

```
library(RCurl)

headerFields = 
  c(Accept = "text/xml",
    'Content-Type' = "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
    SOAPAction = "")

body = '<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sch="http://www.xxxxx.com/esotservice/schema">
   <S:Header/>
<S:Body>
<sch:OwnerOnlyInquiryRequest>
<sch:RequestHeader>
<sch:ClientSystem>ePRS</sch:ClientSystem>
</sch:RequestHeader>
<sch:RequestParameterList>
<sch:RequestParam>12174391</sch:RequestParam>
</sch:RequestParameterList>
<sch:RequestType>CESEID</sch:RequestType>
<sch:PeckingOrder>Pricing</sch:PeckingOrder>
<sch:ViewType>Pricing</sch:ViewType>
</sch:OwnerOnlyInquiryRequest>
</S:Body>
</S:Envelope>'

R <- curlPerform(url = "http://slsesotdevt1.ute.xxxx.com:10149/esot/esotservice.wsdl",
            httpheader = headerFields,
            postfields = body, verbose=TRUE)
```

The response I am getting in RStudio is

[image: Web Service Response]

My intention is to store the webservice response (black text from the image) into object called R in the code with the object class as XML so that I can use XML package to further process the data.  However, when I say print(R) the only response I get is

[image: Value of object stored in R]

After searching the web the response 0 indicates that all went correctly.  But is there a way to actually store the response in R?  If I copy paste the black text appearing in the first image in Rstudio and feed it to xml functions such xmlTreeParse, it gets processed correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fetch the response body using a basicTextGatherer.

For example (taken from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RCurl/RCurl.pdf):

```
library(RCurl)

headerFields = 
  c(Accept = "text/xml",
    'Content-Type' = "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
    SOAPAction = "")

body = '<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sch="http://www.xxxxx.com/esotservice/schema">
   <S:Header/>
<S:Body>
<sch:OwnerOnlyInquiryRequest>
<sch:RequestHeader>
<sch:ClientSystem>ePRS</sch:ClientSystem>
</sch:RequestHeader>
<sch:RequestParameterList>
<sch:RequestParam>12174391</sch:RequestParam>
</sch:RequestParameterList>
<sch:RequestType>CESEID</sch:RequestType>
<sch:PeckingOrder>Pricing</sch:PeckingOrder>
<sch:ViewType>Pricing</sch:ViewType>
</sch:OwnerOnlyInquiryRequest>
</S:Body>
</S:Envelope>'

h = basicTextGatherer()
R <- curlPerform(url = "http://slsesotdevt1.ute.xxxx.com:10149/esot/esotservice.wsdl",
            httpheader = headerFields,
            postfields = body, verbose=TRUE,
writefunction = h$update)
body <- h$value()
```